# How can I delete buttons from an ngprime component?

Tags: html, angular, primeng, picklist

I'm using a picklist primeng component, ant it has buttons that I want to delete but I don't see them in my HTML and y tried searched them but I didn't find them.
This is my HTML.

I got this picklist component from http://primefaces.org/primeng/picklist
and I want to delete the first block of buttons and the last (I only need right and left arrows)

```
<p-pickList [source]="sourceProducts" [target]="targetProducts" sourceHeader="Listado de clases" targetHeader="Clases asignadas" dragdrop="true"
            [sourceStyle]="{'height':'300px'}" [targetStyle]="{'height':'300px'}">
            <ng-template let-product pTemplate="item">
                <div class="product-item">
                    <div class="product-list-detail">
                        <h5 class="mb-2">{{product.name}}</h5>
                        <i class="pi pi-tag product-category-icon"></i>
                        <span class="product-category">{{product.category}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-list-action">
                        <span [class]="'product-badge status-' + product.inventoryStatus.toLowerCase()">{{product.inventoryStatus}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </p-pickList>
```

I reviewed the picklist.d.ts file but I didn't find anything

Comment: You don't want MoveAll button?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add **showSourceControls** and **showTargetControls** properties.

like this :

```
<p-pickList [showSourceControls]="false" [showTargetControls]="false"></p-pickList>
```